Start a long running PHP process via JS/Ajax and monitor progress on admin page
I am developing a plugin, which can import layouts for a certain theme from a remote URL. Those layouts often contain a good amount of images and sometimes even videos. I have a admin page where the user can choose the layout he wants to import. He then clicks the import button, which triggers an Ajax action in PHP to download the layout files and import them into the database.
This can sometimes take up to 5 minutes, depending on the size and complexity of the layout. It works fine when in the php.ini, the max_execution_time is set to > 300 but on many share hosters, the max_execution_time is set to 30-60s, which causes the Ajax action to fail because of a timeout.
Since on the admin page, I show a progress bar, I somehow need the result of that long running process so I was wondering what the best way to achieve this would be.
I read that in WordPress, long running tasks can be scheduled using wp_schedule_single_event() but how can I find out if the process is still running or whether it has finished successfully or with an error?
Or is there something other besides wp_schedule_single_event() which I could use to fire a long running event once via JS and get the result of that process in JS?
I was thinking that maybe I should use 2 ajax calls. One to actually start the event using wp_schedule_single_event() and another one which I fire every 5 seconds or so via JS which then checks if the event has finished. But how would I find out if the event finished?
I hope you understand what I mean and that you can help me out. :)
